# Extract a DataGridView cell value to a variable, when double-clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my C# DataGridView, once I double click on a row, I want the value in the "ID" columns cell to be assigned to a variable. How do I do this??

Comment: Show some code and what you have tried ?

Comment: I have no idea what to try so I don't have any codes to show :/

Comment: A great place to start with any question about a .NET library class is the MSDN documentation.  It'll show you all the methods you can call on an object of that type, all the events you can listen for, etc.  Scanning through that documentation looking for words that describe my problem almost always gives me a lead on the answer.  Here's a link for DataGridView: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: For instance, I notice that DataGridView has an event called "CellDoubleClick".  That might help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a DataGridView, how can I assign a value inside a cell to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164537/in-a-datagridview-how-can-i-assign-a-value-inside-a-cell-to-a-variable). Don't post the same question again. Try to provide more information in the original question.

Comment: Sorry. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataGridView doesn't have row double click event. But you can try cell double click event instead as following:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = "";
        value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Also please note to check if the e.RowIndex > -1, just in case people click the DataGridView header, it will cause exception.

Comment: I have connected my DataGridView to a SQL Database.When I double click on a cell
"Column named ID cannot be found." Comes up.

Comment: @DaveHowson Check your DataGridView in the designer and make sure there is a column and its "Name"(under "Design" tab) property is "ID".

Comment: @DaveHowson Or you can use the cell index(starting from 0) to locate the "ID" column of your DataGridView, it would be easier if you don't need to change the column sequence in the future.

Comment: I cannot use the cell index method because my sequence constantly changes. I double checked in the design view but there is nothing wrong. There is the "ID" column yet the same error comes up.

Comment: Can you post your code for designer so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , Try this :-

```
 private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (datagridview1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
     {
         int selectedrowindex = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

         DataGridViewRow selectedRow = datagridview1.Rows[selectedrowindex];  

         string value= selectedRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();


     }
```

I agree this is not the best approach .

Comment: I have linked my DataGridView to a SQL database, I have a column called ID. To test if this works, I used a textbox with
textbox1.text=value
but it doesnt display the value

Comment: Instead of SelectionChanged, I used CellDoubleClick and this error comes up
"Column named ID cannot be found."

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @mhan0125 and everyone else. That error came up because even though my column was name ID, it was not identified by the code as ID, so I had to go to the 'Edit Column' section and rename it from idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn to ID. Thank you once again..

Comment: Nice to hear you have the issue solved, it would be very helpful to look at the auto-generated designer code. Especially when you want to get these designer information, it is way more faster than to go through the GUI.